# Problems with uploading to blob storage in azure using a cli and .net

Tags: c#, .net, api, azure

Using c# with the .net framework and microsoft azure and i am trying to upload a file in a cli which should be picked up by a webjob. I'm sure the webjob is fine but i am having problems getting upload to work.

```
// Pick URL location of service up from metadata
AudioSamples client = new AudioSamples(new AnonymousCredential());
var id = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();

string path = "api/samples/" + id;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name.");
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{              
   HttpOperationResponse response = await client.PutAsync(path, new StreamContent(stream));
}
```

From what i understand the PutAsync should work for streaming the file but it gives me an error saying the command doesn't exist

this api should also be used with the upload to a blob but im not sure how it connect it to the client.

```
namespace AudioSamples.Controllers
{
   [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
   public class DataController : ApiController
   {
      private const String partitionName = "AudioSamples_Partition_1";
      private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
      private CloudTableClient tableClient;
      private CloudTable table;
      private BlobStorageService _blobStorageService = new BlobStorageService();
      private CloudQueueService _queueStorageService = new CloudQueueService();

      String name;

      public DataController()
      {
         storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsStorage"].ToString());
         tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
         table = tableClient.GetTableReference("AudioSamples");
      }

      private void deleteOldBlobs(AudioSampleEntityModel sample)
      {
         CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.getCloudBlobContainer();
         CloudBlockBlob blob;

         if (sample.Blob != null)
         {
            blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sample.Blob);
            blob.Delete();
         }

         if (sample.SampleBlob != null)
         {
            blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sample.SampleBlob);
            blob.Delete();
         }
      }

      // PUT: api/Data/5
      public IHttpActionResult Put(String id)
      {
         // PUT – see also ProductsController.cs from Lab 4
         // Create a retrieve operation.
         // id is a parameter of method and forms the row key
         TableOperation retrieveOperation =
         TableOperation.Retrieve<AudioSampleEntityModel>(partitionName, id);

         TableResult getOperationResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
         if (getOperationResult.Result == null)
            return NotFound();

         AudioSampleEntityModel sample = (AudioSampleEntityModel)getOperationResult.Result;
         deleteOldBlobs(sample);

         try
         {
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.getCloudBlobContainer();

            name = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), ".mp3");

            String path = "/mp3s" + name;

            var baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
            String sampleURL = baseUrl.ToString() + "/api/data/" + id;

            sample.SampleBlobURL = sampleURL;
            sample.Blob = path;
            sample.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            sample.SampleDate = null;

            var updateOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(sample);

            table.Execute(updateOperation);

            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sample.Blob);

            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            blob.Properties.ContentType = "audio/mpeg3";
            blob.UploadFromStream(request.InputStream);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("DataController(PUT): " + e.Message);
            return BadRequest("DataController(PUT): " + e.Message);
         }

         try
         {
            CloudQueue sampleQueue = _queueStorageService.getCloudQueue();
            var queueMessageSample = new AudioSampleEntityModel(partitionName, id);
            sampleQueue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueMessageSample)));
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("DataController(PUT): " + e.Message);
            return BadRequest("DataController(PUT): " + e.Message);
         }

         System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("*** WebRole: Enqueued '{0}'", sample.Blob));
         return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
      }
   }
}
```

This is the webjob which i think is working fine.

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void GenerateSample(
        [QueueTrigger("audiosamplemaker")] AudioSampleEntityModel sampleInQueue,
        [Table("Samples", "{PartitionKey}", "{RowKey}")] AudioSampleEntityModel sampleInTable,
        [Blob("audiocollection/audio/{queueTrigger}")] CloudBlockBlob inputBlob,
        [Blob("audiocollection/samples/{queueTrigger}")] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob, TextWriter logger,
        [Table("Samples")] CloudTable tableBinding, TextWriter kek)
    {
        //use log.WriteLine() rather than Console.WriteLine() for trace output
        logger.WriteLine("GenerateSample() started...");
        logger.WriteLine("Input blob is: " + sampleInQueue);

        // Open streams to blobs for reading and writing as appropriate.
        // Pass references to application specific methods
        using (Stream input = inputBlob.OpenRead())
        using (Stream output = outputBlob.OpenWrite())
        {
            createSample(input, output, 20);
            outputBlob.Properties.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
            outputBlob.Metadata["Title"] = inputBlob.Metadata["Title"];
        }

        logger.WriteLine("GenerateSample() completed...");
    }

    private static void createSample(Stream input, Stream output, int duration)
    {
        using (var reader = new Mp3FileReader(input, wave => new NLayer.NAudioSupport.Mp3FrameDecompressor(wave)))
        {
            Mp3Frame frame;
            frame = reader.ReadNextFrame();
            int frameTimeLength = (int)(frame.SampleCount / (double)frame.SampleRate * 1000.0);
            int framesRequired = (int)(duration / (double)frameTimeLength * 1000.0);

            int frameNumber = 0;
            while ((frame = reader.ReadNextFrame()) != null)
            {
                frameNumber++;

                if (frameNumber <= framesRequired)
                {
                    output.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length);
                }
                else break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web api controller, the put method only has one parameter named ‘id’. But in your client, you also passed a stream content in put method.
So you couldn’t call web api method successfully. And for this stream content, you could set a string or model type in Put method instead of file stream.

According to your description, I suppose you want to pass data from client to web api, then read data from this file path in web Api and upload data to a blob.
I have created a sample demo to upload a myfile.txt to a Blob. Other data types are similar to this. You could refer to.

Code in Console:

Code in AudioSampleEntityModel class:

```
public class AudioSampleEntityModel : TableEntity
    {
        public AudioSampleEntityModel()
        {

        }
        public AudioSampleEntityModel(string partitionName, string id)
        {

        }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Blob { get; set; }
        public string SampleBlob { get; set; }
        public string SampleBlobURL { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string SampleDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Code in Function.cs:

```
public class Functions
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  pass the content from Queue to Blob(The content is from myfile.txt)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <param name="orderBlob"></param>
        public static void MultipleOutput(
             [QueueTrigger("myqueue2")] AudioSampleEntityModel model,
             [Blob("orders/myfile")] out string orderBlob) //create a container named 'orders'
        {
            orderBlob = model.SampleBlob;    //store the content from SampleBlob property to Blob
        }
}
```

Code in Program:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------Update Employee -------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter id which you want to update");
            string id = Console.ReadLine();
            var response=DemoData(id).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("the data from webapi: "+response);
            var host = new JobHost();
           // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
        public static async Task<string> DemoData(string id)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();        
            string path = "http://localhost:53581/api/values/" + id;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name.");
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
            string filepath = "E:\\JanleyZhang\\" + fileName;
            var filepathJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filepath);// convert other FileStream type to json string
            var data = new StringContent(content: filepathJson,
             encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
             mediaType: "application/json");
            var response = await client.PutAsync(path, data);//get response from web api
            var content = response.Content;
            var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();//read content from response


            //upload the data to a queue
            string connectionString = AmbientConnectionStringProvider.Instance.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringNames.Storage);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

            CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
            CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue2");
            queue.CreateIfNotExists();

            AudioSampleEntityModel model = new AudioSampleEntityModel()
            {
                id=id,
                SampleBlob=result //pass  the result to this property
            };
            queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model))); //store the file content to queue
            return result;
        }
}
```

Code in api controller:

```
public string Put(string id, [FromBody]string filepath) //pass  two parameters
        {
            string b = "The id and model id are not equal.";
            if (id == "1")
            {             
                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filepath);               
                    byte[] byt = new byte[fs.Length];
                    UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
                    while (fs.Read(byt, 0, byt.Length) > 0)
                    {
                       b=temp.GetString(byt);//read the content from myfile.txt
                    // The operation about uploading a blob .........
                    }
                return b;               
            }
            return b;
        }
```

You could see the result like this:
[image: The image about Web Job]

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem now? please let me know.